# Retrieve documents which contain distinct element in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have documents like

```
[{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,2], "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-10-15T06:17:53.946Z") },
{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,3], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:17:54.946Z") },
{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,4], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:17:53.946Z") },
{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,2], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:18:53.946Z") },
{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,3], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:18:53.946Z") },
{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,2],"createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:19:53.946Z") } ]
```

and I want to retrieve only those document which have

1. Distinct nesArray
2. Only latest document

Result should be like

```
   [{"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,4], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:17:53.946Z") },
    {"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,3], "createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:18:53.946Z") },
    {"_id" : "12","name" : "test1", "nesArray" : [1,2],"createdAt" :ISODate("2016-10-15T06:19:53.946Z") }]
```

I tried it with aggregation but I don't want to use aggregation(Mongoose populate is not work with aggregation).

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: @sidgate I tried this with aggregation 
1. sort element by createdAt
2. group document by "nesArray"
3. retrieve latest document of every group by $last.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically what you tried, but getting all fields using `$last` and projecting after to have same structure as in DB:

```
db.coll.aggregate(
  { 
    $sort: { createdAt: 1 }
  }, 
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$nesArray", 
      id: { $last: "$_id" }, 
      name: {$last: "$name"}, 
      createdAt: { $last: "$createdAt"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$id",
      nesArray: "$_id",
      name: 1,
      createdAt: 1
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: I already tried this I need help to get it with aggregation so that I can use populate(Mongoose).

Comment: It's using aggregate. Use populate on the aggregation results, `Model.populate(results, ...)`

Comment: Can you give an example?